# How construct Jerusalem cube and other Menger alike 3D cubes?

Tags: geometry, fractals

**Update** (to clarify)

My end goal is to generate **Menger alike 3D cubes**, as stated in the title.

**OP**

While reading the [`Menger` cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger_sponge), I found something called [`Jerusalem cube`](https://robertdickau.com/jerusalemcube.html). On the same page, there are also many other similar cubes, like

[image]

and many more towards the end on the page (2nd link above).

I looked at the `MengerMesh` but it does not seem to provide this kind of variation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems the logic is if there's a square of certain size (dependent on the level) available, then punch out the shape. I did not notice a nice pattern for this, so I took a brute force approach which means this solution most likely suboptimal.

First let's get the shape we'd like to punch out. To get the connectivity, I'll import the image and turn it to a mesh. To get the correct coordinates, I'll map the pixel approximations to the appropriate values.

The connectivity:

```
im = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uvoz.png"];

mesh = RegionResize[ConnectedMeshComponents[ImageMesh[ColorNegate[im]]][[1]], {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}];
```

Find the correct coordinates:

```
s = Last[x /. NSolve[x + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x == 1, x, Reals]];

nf = Nearest[Union[#, 1 - #] &[{0., s^4, s^3, s^2, s, s + s^4, s + s^4 + s^3}]];

seed = RegionDifference[
  BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Rectangle[]],
  BoundaryMeshRegion[Map[First@*nf, MeshCoordinates[mesh], {2}], MeshCells[mesh, 1]]
]
```

[image]

Now for the code that looks for valid squares of with side lengths `s^lev` and punches out the shape. Note that I didn't take the time to refine `makeRects` or to make it readable.

```
iJerusalemCube[mr_, lev_] := 
  Block[{coords, nn, rects, sub},
    coords = MeshCoordinates[mr];
    nn = Nearest[coords];
    rects = Union @@ makeRects[mr, s^lev] /@ coords;
    sub = RegionUnion @@ (RegionResize[seed, Transpose[#] + s^(4+lev){{1, -1}, {1, -1}}]& /@ rects);
    RegionDifference[mr, sub]
]

makeRects[mr_, lev_][p:{x_, y_}] := 
  First[Reap[
    If[Or[Count[Max[Chop[Abs[First[nn[#]]-#]]]& /@ Tuples[Transpose@{p, p+lev}], 0] > 1, Nor @@ RegionMember[mr, {p + {lev/2, -s^(6+lev)}, p + {-s^(6+lev), lev/2}}]] && RegionWithin[mr, Rectangle[p, p+lev]], Sow[{p, p+lev}]];
    If[Or[Count[Max[Chop[Abs[First[nn[#]]-#]]]& /@ Tuples[Transpose@{{x, y-lev}, {x+lev, y}}], 0] > 1, Nor @@ RegionMember[mr, {p + {lev/2, s^(6+lev)}, p + {-s^(6+lev), -lev/2}}]] && RegionWithin[mr, Rectangle[{x, y-lev}, {x+lev, y}]], Sow[{{x, y-lev}, {x+lev, y}}]];
    If[Or[Count[Max[Chop[Abs[First[nn[#]]-#]]]& /@ Tuples[Transpose@{{x-lev, y}, {x, y+lev}}], 0] > 1, Nor @@ RegionMember[mr, {p + {-lev/2, -s^(6+lev)}, p + {s^(6+lev), lev/2}}]] && RegionWithin[mr, Rectangle[{x-lev, y}, {x, y+lev}]], Sow[{{x-lev, y}, {x, y+lev}}]];
    If[Or[Count[Max[Chop[Abs[First[nn[#]]-#]]]& /@ Tuples[Transpose@{p-lev, p}], 0] > 1, Nor @@ RegionMember[mr, {p + {-lev/2, s^(6+lev)}, p + {s^(6+lev), -lev/2}}]] && RegionWithin[mr, Rectangle[p-lev, p]], Sow[{p-lev, p}]];
  ][[-1]], {}]
```

Here, `iJerusalemCube` finds all rectangles that

- have side lengths `s^lev`
- have a corner that's a coordinate of `mr`
- either

  - has multiple corners that are a coordinate of `mr` (the `nn` part)
  - is tucked into a corner, i.e. does not just meet the boundary at a single point (the `Nor @@ RegionMember` part)
- is fully contained within `mr` (the `RegionWithin` part).

Then it punches out the shape in all valid rectangles.

The main function will iterate this:

```
JerusalemCubeList[lev_Integer?NonNegative] := 
  FoldList[
    iJerusalemCube, 
    BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Rectangle[]], 
    Range[0, lev-1]
  ]

JerusalemCubeList[4]
```

[image]

```
Multicolumn[MapIndexed[
  BoundaryMeshRegion[#1, MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Black, 2 -> ColorData[112][First[#2]]}] &, 
  JerusalemCubeList[5]], 3, Appearance -> "Horizontal"]
```

[image]

And unsurprising that the number of boundary edges grows exponentially:

```
cnts = MeshCellCount[#, 1] & /@ JerusalemCubeList[5]
```

> ```
> {4, 32, 144, 704, 3504, 17504}
> ```

```
FindSequenceFunction[Rest@cnts, n]
```

> ```
> 4/5 (5 + 7 5^n)
> ```

---

To get a cube in 3D, we can intersect the 2D mesh extruded in 3 different directions:

```
mr = Last[JerusalemCubeList[3]];

bmr = BoundaryMesh[RegionProduct[mr, Line[{{0.}, {1.}}]]];

RegionIntersection @@ (
  BoundaryMeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[bmr][[All, #]], MeshCells[bmr, 2]] & /@ 
  {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 2}})
```

[image]

Comment: Could these 2D images be turned into the 3D "cube"?

Comment: @ChenStatsYu It's annoying and rude to [move the goalpost](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1808/10397). This answer does solve your question. If now you have another problem for which you need help, even if related, you should post another question.

Comment: @rhermans Sorry if that is not clear. I did say in the `title` that I am hoping to generate the `3D` of these cubes too. I don't think the `goal` has changed at all. I do appreciate the answer and I have already voted an `up` too.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu See my edit. It wasn't clear to me in the question you were looking for a 3D version.

Comment: @ChipHurst Sorry about that. Thanks!